# How to run specified program?

Tags: vb.net

How can I make it so that when a user clicks a button (in VB.NET or C#, preferably VB) it runs the Intel AppUp Center if the user has it on his/her machine? would I use a proccess for this?
Would this work?

1. Find if PC is 32 or 64 bit
2. if 32, go to default "C:\Program Files\Intel\IntelAppStore\bin\appup_intel.exe", if 64, go to "C:\Program Files(x86)\Intel\IntelAppStore\bin\appup_intel.exe
3. run specified path.

is there something wrong with including the (x86) for 64 bit machines? I mean, is the (x86) added automatically if the OS detects that the specified file is in the Program Files(x86) directory?

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.Start("Path to Intel AppUp Center")
```

There are various overloads for this method - the details can be found on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) - from the simple like this, to one that takes command line options and user name & password as arguments.

Comment: But is there a way to find the path to the AppUp automatically? what about x64 path differences (its 32 bit.)? On my 64bit machine, it puts it in "Program Files(x86)"

Comment: @Hello all - How do you mean "automatically"? You need to start somewhere, our computers are not mind readers yet.

Comment: Check if this application has an entry in the registry, containing a path to its installation directory or the binary itself. This is usually the case in most applications.

Comment: 1. find if computer is 32 or 64 bit

Comment: @Hello all - please edit your question, instead of adding comments to an answer.

Comment: 2. if 32, go to "Program Files\Intel\IntelAppStore\bin\appup_intel"

Comment: @Hello all - just to reiterate what @Oded said. Stack Overflow is **not** a forum. If you have more information edit your question. If you have a supplementary problem post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{   
 if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\IntelAppStore\bin\appup_intel.exe")
    {
         Process p = new Process();
         p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\IntelAppStore\bin\appup_intel.exe");
         p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\IntelAppStore\bin";
         p.Start();
    }
    else
    {
         Process p = new Process();
         p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Intel\IntelAppStore\bin\appup_intel.exe");
         p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Intel\IntelAppStore\bin";
         p.Start();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Intel AppUp Center does not exist");
     MessageBox.Show(e.Message+Environmnet.NewLine+e.StackTrace);
}
```